# Trying to get list of Venues with respect to Suppliers

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi guys so i am trying to build a report where i have to show new customers this month compared to last month. I am able to calculate new customers fine but i have to show them in a Matrix in Power Bi. This is the Code i am using

```
New Customers This Month = 
VAR ThisMonth =
    SELECTEDVALUE( DailyReport[DateCreated].[MonthNo])
VAR ThisYEAR =
    SELECTEDVALUE(DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year])
VAR SelectedSupplier = 
    SELECTEDVALUE(DailyReport[SupplierName])
VAR LastMonth = ThisMonth - 1
VAR CustomersThisMonth =
    DISTINCT(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FILTER( ALL( DailyReport ), DailyReport[DateCreated].[MonthNo] = ThisMonth && DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year] = ThisYEAR && DailyReport[SupplierName] = SelectedSupplier),
            "C1", DailyReport[VenueName]
        )
    )
VAR CustomersLastMonth =
    DISTINCT(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FILTER( ALL( DailyReport ), DailyReport[DateCreated].[MonthNo] = LastMonth && DailyReport[DateCreated].[Year] = ThisYEAR && DailyReport[SupplierName] = SelectedSupplier),
            "C1", DailyReport[VenueName]
        )
    )
VAR T1 =
    EXCEPT(CustomersThisMonth, CustomersLastMonth )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX( T1, [C1], ", " )
```

I am getting result like this, two columns one for supplier and one for new venues this month

[getting result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOCX6.png)
But expected result should be like this, you know like a list

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvPyi.png)
i think it may be causing due to how i am concatening it in the last line in code
and please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: You've already asked this question, and your expected output still doesn't make sense. What exactly do you mean by "a list"?

Comment: Splliers and Venues should be in the same column in Matrix